# using react-admin, If the data object has depth, how can I access it from the filed in the <Datagrid>

Tags: react-admin

Im using
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-admin": "^3.6.0",

and I used to access data below. It works !

```js
<Datagrid>
              <TextField source="product.no" label="Product ID" />
              <TextField source="productModelPiName" label="Product Model(PI)" />
              <TextField source="version" label="Product Version" />
              <TextField source="inStock" label="In stock" />
              <TextField source="outOfStock" label="Out of stock" />
              <TextField source="disposal" label="Disposal" />
</Datagrid>
```

but the server response is changed.
so I need to access like `<TextField source = product.di.productModelPiName />`
but It doesn't work.
How can I use react-admin for this case???

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer to your query in the code snippet you pasted:
For instance, if you have an API giving a JSON response like:

```
[{
    "product": {
        "no": 1,
        ...
    }
},
{
    "product": {
        "no": 2,
        ...
    }
}]
```

you can access the value for `no` inside your `<Datagrid>` like:

```js
<TextField source="product.no" label="Product ID" />
```

Comment: yes it works as far as 2 depth object. but the response object has chaged to
[{ product: { no: 1, di : { productPiName: A, somethingA : 1, somethingB: 2},...}]
but I realized that it didn't work because maybe there is no id key for unique key for table rendering!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, There is typo  "Textfiled" -> "Textfield"

please paste your JSON or Object type data structure

then I or other developers can give you the right help.